# I'm trying to create a custom toast on a fragment. But when writing such code, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: android

```
fun Toast.showCustomToast() {
    val bindingtost = ToastBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

    this.apply {
        setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0)
        duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        setView(bindingtost.root)
        show()
    }
}
Toast(requireContext()).showCustomToast()
```

Comment: I guess the problem is with `ToastBinding.inflate()` call without passing a `parent: ViewGroup`. Please try passing your fragment's or activity's root view to `showCustomToast()` method and inflate toast view with it.

Comment: val bindingtost =  ToastBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, binding.frame, true)

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout{b85a05a V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,264 #7f0a0351 app:id/constLay} not attached to window manager

Comment: Simply you can inflate your toast view inside `onCreateView` if you are in a fragment, or inside `onCreate` if you are in an activity. Try this approach and see if it works. And double check your view to make sure it's height and width ARE NOT zero